# Adding xml modification to Magento custom theme

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

I have custom theme for magento. I made some modification in local.xml file which works fine, but I would like to made modification who won't be overwrite after update.

I made a new xml file (mod.xml) and insert it to my theme layout folder - how to run it on site?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

<default>
    <!-- move the cookies info block from the bottom block to the top -->
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>global_cookie_notice</name>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
    </reference>
</default>

</layout>
```

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own module. In the config.xml of your module, you can define your custom xml file. This will add your custom theme file to the layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_module>
                    <file>mod.xml</file>
                </my_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Whole new module for one modification? Is there any tutorial how to build new SIMPLE module?

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to create a new module: http://alanstorm.com/magento_config
You only need the 'bare-bones' setup and update the config.xml according to my example above.

Comment: I found this site http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ - it generate whole module itself. With your code works like I want to - Thanks!